# Render buttons as divs to avoid inherited button styles

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

We embed React components in our website. There are some basic styles which apply to our buttons, which come from the user agent (such as outline on focus) and from the HTML/CSS environment where we embed our React components.

We want our React components to be style independent. Since we also use our components in widgets, we can't really control the external environment.

One solution is for our basic Button element to render `<div role="button" ...` instead of an actual button element.

Is there any reason to avoid this practice, such as browser support, functionality, etc.?

Comment: Don't do this. Don't. It's accessibility hell. `<button>`s are interactive. `<div>`s are not. This is [worst practice](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html#WorstPractice).

Comment: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role)

Comment: @chriskirknielsen, just found out it will not be focusable. THX

Comment: @chriskirknielsen, your comment - Just the fact that it isn't automatically focusable, and therefor will or might cause accessibility issues answers my question. Make it into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you for understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. Don't. It's accessibility hell. `<button>`s are interactive. `<div>`s are not. This is [worst practice](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html#WorstPractice).

As you commented, focus is not available either on a `<div role="button" ...>`, which is quite nicely baked into a `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

while, i'm not sure but maybe we can control it using unique/different `class name`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this (you can add it to your reset.css):

```
    *:focus { outline-width: 0px !important; }
```

This should completely eliminate any visible outline, despite element's class name (or if it doesn't have a class name).

If at some point you'll need outline back, you can add it directly to your  custom class.